# Navigation view text size wont change in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, navigationview

Im trying to change the size of the item text of my navigation view in android studio but every time it appears the same. I have tried creating an style like the following:

```
<style name="ItemStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
```

or

```
<style name="ItemStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
```

or

```
<style name="ItemStyle"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
```

but none of these seem to work this is my navigation view code

```
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/ItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        >
```

also here is my nav_menu code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/homeicon"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_invite"
        android:icon="@drawable/invite"
        android:title="Invite friends" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_history"
        android:icon="@drawable/history"
        android:title="Ride history" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_payment"
        android:icon="@drawable/payment"
        android:title="Payment" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_help"
        android:icon="@drawable/help"
        android:title="Help" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings"
        android:title="Settings" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_driver"
        android:icon="@drawable/drive"
        android:title="Drive" />
</menu>
```

I would appreciate if someone can help find out whats wrong with it. Thanks

Comment: Actually your code looks fine, make sure you are adding your style in values/styles.xml. Also make sure to try bigger size just to make sure that it's not working and you're seeing it clearly

Comment: I've tried with 100dp , 100sp and the text remains in the default. Also I have tried running the app in an android device and in the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try the `textAppearance`

Your style:

```
<style name="MyDesign" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Implementation:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/MyDesign"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        >
```